# Take the value and create filter from input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to take text from selected options and wrap it into div and append that div to the one with class appendElements? 
here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2w5dp7vk/14/ I am trying to add filter when i check some option or when i type something in input field. I want to be able to take the value from input or select option and wrap that value into div tag and append it on .appendElements when i click on done button.

```
<div class="appendElements"></div>

<div class="searchFilter">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="published">Published</option>
        <option value="draft">Draft</option>
        <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
        <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does this question received upvotes if the asker didn't showed any code, idea or attemp to achieve what he is aksing?

Comment: here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2w5dp7vk/7/
I am trying to add filter when i check some option or when i type something in input field. I want to be able to take the value from input or select option and wrap that value into div tag and append it on .selected-filters.

Comment: add it to the question as an edit

Answer (score 1):

First, you've to attach a `change` event to your select èlement `.searchFilter`, then when the user changes you've to get the text of the selected option using `$('.searchFilter option:selected').text()` and attach it to your output div `.appendElements`, like:

**jQuery suggestion :**

```js
var selectElement = $('.selectpicker');

selectElement.on('change', function() {
  var selected_option_text = selectElement.find('option:selected').text();

  $('.appendElements').text(selected_option_text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="searchFilter">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="published">Published</option>
    <option value="draft">Draft</option>
    <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
    <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>
<div class="appendElements"></div>
```

**VanillaJS suggestion :**

```js
var selectElement = document.querySelector('.selectpicker');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var selected_option_text = selectElement.selectedOptions[0].text;
  document.querySelector('.appendElements').textContent = selected_option_text;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="searchFilter">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="published">Published</option>
    <option value="draft">Draft</option>
    <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
    <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>
<div class="appendElements"></div>
```

Comment: @denis-omerovic does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the select when it changes and set it as the `textContent` of the div in which you want to display the value of the select.

```html
<div class="searchFilter">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" onchange="showChanges()" id="selectpicker">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="published">Published</option>
            <option value="draft">Draft</option>
            <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
            <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p/>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function showChanges(){
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = document.getElementById("selectpicker").value;
}
</script>
```

jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchFilter">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" onchange="showChanges()" id="selectpicker">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="published">Published</option>
                <option value="draft">Draft</option>
                <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
                <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <p/>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
    function showChanges(){
      $('#result').text($('#selectpicker').val());
    }
    </script>
```